# How to deploy a static website to Azure from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an existing website that I would like to deploy on **Azure**, using **Visual Studio Team Services**. The website is made up of static files, there's no ASP.NET or anything else involved.

Within Visual Studio Team Services, I created a build which executes `npm install` and a `gulp` build. This results in a `dist` folder containing all the files for the website. In Azure, everything is set up correctly (subscription, web app,...).

However, I'm unsure on how to push my code to Azure. Exploring the options in the Release tab in VSTS, an 'artifact' always seems to be required, but I just have a bunch of files. I need to publish the files in the `dist` folder and make sure `index.html` is served.

How can I do that?

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653643/how-to-deploy-a-simple-static-micro-site-on-microsoft-azure) one, however, the answers all state to start from Azure, and do not mention how to deploy existing code using Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to create the artifact yourself, which can be as simple as a **zip file** containing the static website files. The zip file should be copied as an artifact to the $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) target directory. Next, you can use a simple **Web App deployment task** to publish the zip file to Azure. If `index.html` is in the root directory, Azure is smart enough to serve it.

Below is a working build and deploy flow. It assumes `gulp` is used to build the website and write the build output (i.e. the static files) to a dist folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to deploy from a source control, if you take a look under "Settings" for your Website in the Azure portal you will probably see ["Continuous deployment"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/).

From there you can deploy from Visual Studio Team Services, Github, etc.

Every check-in will be deployed, also wrong ones, so you may want a introduce a staging environment as a [deployment slot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) as well, where you can swap staging with production whenever you feel your site is ready for production.

Comment: Well that certainly is an option, but I would like to control releases with VSTS, rather than setting up CD from Azure. I indeed have a test, staging and production environment, and I would like to 'promote' a release from one deployment slot to the next.

Comment: If you want to do everything from Visual Studio Online you have to look into Release Management at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx

Comment: If you only want to use VSO for source control and work tasks you can take a look at https://www.appveyor.com/ that will automate your builds and deployment

Answer (score 1):

Without the need to create an artifact, another solution could be FTP deployment after creating an Service Endpoint in VSTS

[image]

[image]