# How do I deploy static assets from VSTS to multiple applications?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Apologies if this question has already been answered. I've tried looking around, but may not have done a great job!

My azure deployment consists of 4 web sites deployed from VSTS that all share common web assets hosted on an Azure CDN. I would like to create a single "build" (or release) in VSTS so that I can build all the client-assets at once and deploy them to the CDN endpoint as well as the 4 running app services for fallback.

My initial approach used FTP tasks for the web servers. This worked but took almost an hour to ftp 500+ files to each website. I then attempted the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116582/how-to-deploy-a-static-website-to-azure-from-visual-studio-team-services). Though I was able to zip up the assets, my drop file had the structure of:
 - assets
 - WebAssets.zip

Eg. "WebAssets.zip" was just a compressed copy of "assets" and I was unable to deploy this file to the proper location on the websites, "/site/wwwroot/wwwroot".

Is there a better way to copy these assets to each web service? Here is the structure of the "ftp" version of copying the assets:

[image: FTP based asset deployment]

Any help or direction pointing would be appreciated.

Update: just wanted to clarify that the current process does indeed work. It just takes between 30min and an hour to complete. I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly and that there is not a better way.

Comment: Can't you just use `Azure File Copy` task?

Comment: Unless I am missing something (which could be highly likely) ... the four FTP tasks need to copy files to each App Service. I am using the Azure File Copy to go to the CDN and that works like a charm ... it is just getting the static files to the App Services. I don't see any combinations in the copy task to target the App Services.

Comment: You may check `Azure App Service Deploy` task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT ... that was my second attempt. I added a link to the article that I tried to implement. I was able to create the "drop" file that contained my assets and then a zip file of my assets, but I could not get it to deploy to the server itself. I'll keep trying but it looks like what I've attempted may have been the only possible scenarios. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Do you get any error during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

With Azure App Service Deployment task, you need to check **Publish using Web Deploy** option if you want to extract the zip folder.

On the other hand, to improve the performance, you can setup a private build agent that has the high performance (e.g. Network, Memory, CPU)

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts)

Comment: Yes. I had this check-box selected. Even though the task succeeded I could not find where the files were extracted too, and for sure were not in the place I expected them to be ... "site/wwwroot/wwwroot/"

Comment: By default, the files are deployed to site/wwwroot, you can check files by accessing https://{app service name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole. What's the result if you just deploy these files directly? (uncheck Publish using web deploy option and specify the parent folder of wwwroot folder?