# Host static HTML in Azure Web App Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I'm azure beginner

I've created nodejs service and deployed it to Azure Web App service, it works as expected.
So, I have resource group **mars-app** and existing Web App service application **my-mars-web-app**.

Now, I want to add static HTML file, to show it when user goes to root URL https://***.azurewebsites.net/

To achieve it,

1. I have cloned github repo with client side to azure storage with azure cli help
2. In cliend code folder, I have tried to run **az webapp up -g mars-app -n my-mars-web-app --html**, but every time I'm receiving:

*The webapp my-mars-web-app is a Linux app. The code detected at '/home/serhii/azure-website' will default to '<module 'os' from '/opt/az/lib/python3.6/os.py'>'. Please create a new app to continue this operation.*

Because of above error, I have added index.html to dist diretory in my backend app

```js
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendfile('dist/index.html');
 });
```

and it works. But I'm not sure it is a good solution

**What the best practice to add static HTML files to existing Web App service?**

This question may be a dublicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653643/how-to-deploy-a-simple-static-micro-site-on-microsoft-azure), but it was asked 5 years ago, so maybe something changed.

P.S. I know about **Static Web Apps**, but it is in preview and I'm interested in more generic solutions.

Thanks in advance

[UPDATE]
Here an [article](https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321) about deploying react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why you want to add static HTML files to existing web app services, for update or others*?

In my opinon, now that you have used git, you can use [**continuous deployment**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment).

When you modify your program (add new or modify files), in the Action of github, you will see the program start to deploy again. This should be the best deployment plan.

Comment: You can do some operations in git by [command line](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line).

Comment: Is it possible to deploy front end part from other repo that backend part? Assume I have two repos - backend and front end, is it still possible to use CD for it?

Comment: @SerhiiBilyk Of course you can, but you may need to use a [staging slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) to implement hot updates.